# How to get month format with 0 after evaluate using Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I try to get month and year format like "06/19" after evaluated month but I got just "6/19".

```
Month and year
   ${currentYear}=    Get Current Date  result_format=%y
   ${currentDate}=    Get Current Date
   ${datetime} =  Convert Date  ${currentDate}    datetime
   ${getMonth}=   evaluate   ${datetime.month} - 1
   log to console   ${getMonth}/${currentYear}
```

I already tried another way by created variable @{MONTHSNO}    ${EMPTY}  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 and return ${MONTHSNO}[${getMonth}]/${currentYear} I got 06/19 but I'm not sure the robot have another way to convert month to "06" by without to make the variable like these.

Comment: look at this library -  https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Custom%20timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this by using a custom keywords that will return the date in month/year format

Then you can use `relativedelta()` to subtract a month from your date

to install dateutil:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

test.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def return_current_date_minus_one_month():
    strDate = datetime.today()
    Subtracted_date = strDate + relativedelta(months=-1)
    Date = Subtracted_date.strftime('%m/%y')
    return Date
```

test.robot

```
*** Settings ***

Library  test.py

*** Test Cases ***

Month and year
   ${current_date} =  Test.Return Current Date Minus One Month
   log  ${current_date}
```

result =  `${current_date} = 06/19`

Answer (score 1):

When you run Evaluate command, you are running python commands. So let's take a look at datetime docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

They have this part in the end saying that library time can be useful. So I suggest you to use this command to return month in 0X format:

```
${getMonth}=   evaluate   time.strftime("%m")
```

This just return 07 to me (because now it's July)

Comment: I have to minus 1 month for result and when I use ${getMonth}=   evaluate   ${datetime} - 1  time.strftime("%m") I got error "ImportError: No module named strftime("%m")".

Answer (score 0):

You can substract from your current date one month like this with the DateTime Library:

```
${date1}=  Get Current Date  result_format=%d.%m.%Y 
${date2}=  Substract Time To Date  ${date1}  30 days  date_format=%d.%m.%Y result_format=%m.%Y
```

maybe this helps

Comment: Thank you for your idea but some months have 31 days.

Comment: Sadly there are no Time string for Month in this Lib